# Can't forward to port 8787

Tags: port-forwarding, ubuntu-16.04

We have an instance of R studio running on port 8787 under Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. We can access it normally from work using:

```
server_url:8787
```

When not at work, after connecting to work VPN, we normally set an ssh forward using:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8787:localhost:8787 username@server_url
```

And then, access R studio through a browser using the address:

```
localhost:8787
```

Recently, we have been unable to access R studio from outside work (from work, it is still fine)

Forwards to other ports continue to work normally, but forwards to port 8787 don't seem to work anymore.

Any reason what could be causing this and/or how can I properly diagnose? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your local Port 8787? SSH port redirecting will not work, if the port is already occupied.

Comment: If you are on VPN, why do you need the port forwarded in an ssh tunnel? You should just connect normally, as you do from work.

Comment: @bjoster, yes I checked, port 8787 is free

Comment: @MichaelHampton, we can access the server through ssh, but when we need to access a specific port on a broswer, we can only do it through a port forward.
For instance: ssh username@server_url from command line works,
but server_url:3000 in a browser does not work, we need to do:
ssh -N -f -L localhost:3000:localhost:3000 username@server_url and then access it on a browser using localhost:3000

Comment: You should not need to do that at all! That is the point. Something is wrong with your VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that one of my colleagues ran the following command from the server instead of running it from the client:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8787:localhost:8787 username@server_url
```

After killing the corresponding process, port forwarding is working as expected.